# Read data from server with Sencha touch

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, sencha-touch

I have a test in sencha touch, code is as follow

test.js

```
Ext.setup({
   onReady: function() {        
        Ext.regModel('car', {
            fields: [                               
                {name: 'manufacture',type: 'string'},
                {name: 'model',   type: 'string'},
                {name: 'price',    type: 'decimal'}
            ]
        });
        var productsList = new Ext.DataView({
            store: new Ext.data.Store({
                model: 'car',
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url : 'cars.json',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'data'
                    }
                },
                autoLoad : true
            }),
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<tpl for=".">',
                    '<div class="item">',
                        '"{manufacture}"',
                        '"{model}"',
                        '"{price}"',
                    '</div>',
                '</tpl>'
            ),
            itemSelector: "div.item",
            fullscreen: true
        });
   }
});
```

the json code is (cars.json)

> {"data":[{"manufacture":"SSANYONG","model":"ACTYON","price":100000},{"manufacture":"SUZUKI","model":"ALTO","price":80000}],"results":3}

this example works, but i have read data from server, the code from a c#/aspx is as follow

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<car> oList = new List<car>();

    car c = new car();
    c.manufacture = "SSANYONG";
    c.model = "ACTYON";
    c.price = 100000;

    car d = new car();
    d.manufacture = "SUZUKI";
    d.model = "ALTO";
    d.price = 80000;

    oList.Add(c);
    oList.Add(d);
    string sJSON;
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(oList);
    sJSON=string.Concat("{\"data\":", sJSON);
    sJSON=string.Concat(sJSON,",\"results\":3}");

    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Response.Write(sJSON);
}
```

the car class is

```
public class car
{
    public string manufacture { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
}
```

when i run the aspx, in localhost displays the same text that cars.json, i try with differents code

changes "application/json" to "application/x-json",
        "application/json" to   "text/javascript", 
        "proxy type:ajax"  to   "scripttag",
        "proxy type:ajax"  to   "rest"

not working.

Answer (score 0):

Example finally works!, just have to accommodate the APPLICATION aspx on the server (not localhost and the competent department course), also host the application of sencha touch on the server so that everything works